# Как сделать графическое отображение процесса сортировки в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, gui

Есть некий не отсортированный список, который дальше будет отсортирован.

Мне нужно графически показать этот процесс, именно процесс, 
а не просто отсортированный список.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как показать анимацию изменения гистограммы в python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475742/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


def bubbleSort(elements, switch, compare):
    n = len(elements)
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(0, n - i - 1):
            if compare(elements[j], elements[j + 1]):
                switch(elements[j], elements[j + 1])
                elements[j], elements[j + 1] = (
                    elements[j + 1],
                    elements[j],
                )
                yield


class MRE(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.n = 100
        self.items = []
        
        self.view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        self.view.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        self.view.scale(1, -1)
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.view)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=10, timeout=self.next_step)

    def main(self):
        self.value_gen()
        self.start_algorithm()
        self.show()

    def value_gen(self):
        height = 100
        width = 2

        for value in range(self.n):
            h = random.randrange(0, height)
            item = self.scene.addRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, width, h))
            item.setPos(2 * value * width, 0)
            item.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen))
            item.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("black"))
            self.items.append(item)
        self.fix_size()

    def start_algorithm(self):
        self.algorithm = bubbleSort(self.items, self.switch, self.compare)
        self.timer.start()

    def next_step(self):
        try:
            next(self.algorithm)
        except StopIteration:
            self.timer.stop()

    def switch(self, item_a, item_b):
        pos_a = item_a.scenePos()
        pos_b = item_b.scenePos()
        item_a.setPos(pos_b)
        item_b.setPos(pos_a)
        self.fix_size()

    def compare(self, item_a, item_b):
        return item_a.rect().height() < item_b.rect().height()

    def fix_size(self):
        self.view.fitInView(self.scene.itemsBoundingRect())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.fix_size()
        super().resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MRE()
    w.resize(600, 400)
    w.main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, простите, но можете подсказать, как сделать ,чтобы не от большего к меньшему, а от меньшего к большему сортировалось?

Comment: @user532904  пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @user532904 я вам предлагаю попробовать это сделать самостоятельно. Если не получится- зададите новый вопрос и покажите, что вы пробовали сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос задан несколько неточно, но предположу что вы хотите увидеть массив на каждом шаге сортировки.

```
import time
from random import randint
# Функция вывода на экран массива
def print_array(a):
    print("\033[%d;%dH" % (0, 0))  # это нужно для перемещения курсора (чтобы массив выводился на экране в одном и том же месте)
    print("                                  ")
    print("\033[%d;%dH" % (0, 0))
    print(a)

# тут будет ваш цикл сортировки
for i in range(10):
    # в примере просто генерируем новый массив. У вас тут будет реализована логика сортировки
    a = [randint(0,9) for x in range(10)]
    # выводим массив и делаем паузу в 1сек 
    print_array(a)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: А как собственно графиком это показать? Даже пусть дан уже определенный массив, например, [5,7,1], он уже отсортирован [1,5,7], мне нужно графически показать как меняется график [5,7,1] на [1,5,7]

Answer (score 0):

Берём код bubble_sort [отсюда](https://realpython.com/sorting-algorithms-python/#implementing-bubble-sort-in-python):

```python
def bubble_sort(array):
    n = len(array)
    for i in range(n):
        already_sorted = True
        for j in range(n - i - 1):
            if array[j] > array[j + 1]:
                array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]
                already_sorted = False
        if already_sorted:
            break
    return array
bubble_sort([4,5,3,2,1])
```

Вставляем код [сюда](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html). Теперь можно пошагово посмотреть что происходит с списком и как он сортируется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно также сделать графическое отображение в [graphviz](https://graphviz.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Если размер списка не очень велик, то после каждого шага сортировки можно строить столбчатую диаграмму (индекс-значение), например, в matplotlib, а для совсем маленьких списков (десяток элементов) можно даже в консоли лежачие столбики выводить