# Как показать анимацию изменения гистограммы в python?

Tags: python

Есть функция сортировки массива,ao это размер массива, как создать анимацию гистограммы начального списка, который в последствии сортируется(столбцы меняются или как-нибудь по-другому).То есть изначально показывается неотсортированный массив, который меняется и превращается в отсортированный

```
def selection_sort(ao):
    a = [i for i in range(1, ao + 1)]
    random.shuffle(a)
    N = len(a)
    for i in range(N - 1):
        m = a[i]
        p = i
        for j in range(i + 1, N):
            if m > a[j]:
                m = a[j]
                p = j

        if p != i:
            t = a[i]
            a[i] = a[p]
            a[p] = t
    print(a)
```

Comment: А в чём вы хотите анимацию то? Вариантов много, где и как её можно отрисовывать.

Comment: Можно, например, массив ,длиной 5,следовательно 5 столбцов и можно просто, чтобы они начали переставляться из-за сортировки(в начале на графике видны столбы в хаотичном порядке, потом может через пол секунду, но не сразу, они начали переставляться)

Comment: Я имею в виду, что графику тоже можно много в чём рисовать. Можно в `tkinter`, можно просто через `matplotlib` сделать анимацию в интерактивном питоне, можно ещё в чём-то. Вам вообще всё-равно в чём или нет?

Comment: Я знаком и с тем и с тем, но можно лучше в tkinter, просто мне еще нужно сделать такую штуку, чтобы можно было выбрать строить график или нет

Comment: А если в целом, то можно и tkinter и matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант анимации на `matplotlib` бонус в том, что ее можно записать в видео (не всегда но может быть нужно).

Основная идея в алгоритм превращаем в `генератор` с помощью `yield`, который на каждой итерации будет возвращать состояние и к примеру 2 индекса для того чтобы мы их могли подсветить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

sz = 50

def selection_sort(ao):
    a = [i for i in range(1, ao + 1)]
    random.shuffle(a)
    N = len(a)
    for i in range(N - 1):
        m = a[i]
        p = i
        for j in range(i + 1, N):
            if m > a[j]:
                m = a[j]
                p = j

        if p != i:
            t = a[i]
            a[i] = a[p]
            a[p] = t
        yield (a, i, p)
    #print(a)       
            
def barlist_step():
  return next(arr) # итерируемся по сортировке

fig = plt.figure()
# инициализируем генератор
arr = selection_sort(sz)
# инициализируем бары barlist_step()[0] = массив 
barcollection = plt.bar(range(sz), barlist_step()[0], color='blue')

def animate(current_frame):
    print(current_frame)
    try:
        # получаем значения сортировки и два индекса перестановки
        y, c1, c2 = barlist_step()
        for i, b in enumerate(barcollection):
            b.set_height(y[i])
            if (i == c1 or i == c2): 
                # подсвечиваем выбранные индексы
                b.set_color('red') 
            else:
                b.set_color('blue') 
    except StopIteration: # итерации закончились
        pass # можно вывести количество итераций           

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig,
    animate,
    frames=100, # количество кадров (зависит от алгоритма)
    repeat=False,
    interval=100 # задает интервал и fps для видео
)

# для записи анимации можно воспользоваться следующей строкой
# anim.save('sort.mp4',writer=animation.FFMpegWriter())
# важно помнить что итератор сортировки отработает только 1 раз
# и не будет работать на следующей строке plt.show()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, это просто замечательный код, который мне идеально подходит

Comment: пожалуйста, рад что удалось помочь)

Comment: @user532904 так же Вы можете расширить код — подсчитывая количество итераций сортировки, но для этого массив нужно создавать вне функции сортировки  что в принципе вполне очевидно, функция сортировки должна заниматься только сортировкой, имея массив снаружи вы сможете предварительно посчитать сколько конкретно для него нужно итераций что позже использовать в количестве фреймов.

Comment: Хорошо, я вас понял